# Getting all categories or not the right categories back

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

So if I have, on a new installation: Categories of Uncategorised and Apples, then write a new blog with Apples as the category and view that post - The categories at the bottom of the page are: Uncategorised and Apples.

My code is as follows:

```
$aisis_category_list = array(
       'orderby' => 'id',
       'order' => 'ASC',
       'style' => 'none',
       'title_li'=> '',
);
```

Then I do:

```
wp_list_categories($aisis_category_list);
```

Why am I not getting the specific category I selected back as the only category?

**note:** on rare occasions I only get "uncategorised" back as the category for that post when I am 100% sure I chose only apples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your looking to get the categories of a current post, then you should use:

```
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
```

[wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category)